# Adding drop downs (selection lists) to user registration page Plone

Tags: plone

### My problem & fixing attempts

I have a Plone 4 site which I have used [collective.examples.userdata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.examples.userdata) on in order to register new custom fields on the registration form and `@@personal-information` page. One of my fields needs to be a selection list allowing the user to specify which team from the organisation they are in.

I have successfully got the selection list appearing on the registration form and `@@personal-information` forms, however I am falling flat when trying to figure out how to add it to the `mysite.com/portal_memberdata` page.

I have tried adding a field to this page with the following information:

**Name**: team

**Type**: selection

**Value**: getTeamValue

`getTeamValue` is a Python script that contains:

```
return ('(nothing selected)','Volunteers','Trustees',
'Quality, Education &amp; Learning','Bereavement Support',
'Supportive Care Services','Hospice at Home',
'Day Services','Medical Team','Inpatient Unit'
,'HR','Support Services','Accounts &amp; IT',
'Communications','Trading','Fundraising')
```

Now when I alter the drop down lists value and try to save the changes, (on `@@personal-information`) I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 795, in __call__
  Module five.formlib.formbase, line 50, in update
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 776, in update
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 620, in success
  Module plone.app.users.browser.account, line 64, in handle_edit_action
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 543, in applyChanges
  Module zope.formlib.form, line 538, in applyData
  Module zope.schema._bootstrapfields, line 227, in set
  Module kcs.userdata.adapter, line 20, in set_team
  Module Products.PlonePAS.tools.memberdata, line 261, in setMemberProperties
  Module Products.PlonePAS.sheet, line 75, in setProperty
  Module Products.PlonePAS.sheet, line 72, in validateProperty
PropertyValueError: Invalid value (Volunteers) for property 'team' of type lines
```

I have also tried setting the **Value** field to both `lines` and `string`, but both result in the same traceback, however the bottom line's `lines` word is replaced for `string` or `selection` etc.

### Code used

These are the excerpts of code I use in my add-on to add the selection box to the user registration:

**adapter.py**

```
def get_team(self):
  return self.context.getProperty('team','')
def set_team(self, value):
  return self.context.setMemberProperties({'team': value})
team = property(get_team, set_team)
```

**userdataschema.py**

```
team = schema.Choice(
  title=_(u'label_team', default=u'Select your team'),
  description=_(u'help_team', default=u"Select your team from the list below"),
  values = [
    _(u'Volunteers'),
    _(u'Trustees'),
    _(u'Quality, Education & Learning'),
    _(u'Bereavement Support'),
    _(u'Supportive Care Services'),
    _(u'Hospice at Home'),
    _(u'Day Services'),
    _(u'Medical Team'),
    _(u'Inpatient Unit'),
    _(u'HR'),
    _(u'Support Services'),
    _(u'Accounts & IT'),
    _(u'Communications'),
    _(u'Trading'),
    _(u'Fundraising')
  ],
  required=True,
)
```

**memberdata_properties.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_memberdata" meta_type="Plone Memberdata Tool">
  <property name="position" type="string"></property>
  <property name="linkedin" type="string"></property>
  <property name="team" type="choice"></property>
  <property name="accept" type="boolean"></property>
</object>
```

**propertiestool.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_properties" meta_type="Plone Properties Tool">
  <object name="site_properties" meta_type="Plone Property Sheet">
    <property name="user_registration_fields" type="lines">
      <element value="position" />
      <element value="linkedin" />
      <element value="team" />
      <element value="accept" />
    </property>
  </object>
</object>
```

Let me know if I need to provide more information and any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might not be the cause of your problem, but you're running the valid values in `userdataschema.py` through the i18n layer by passing them through `_`, and you're not doing the same for the values in your getTeamValues. If you're confident you don't need multi-language support for this, I'd try removing the `_()`s to simplify matters.

Comment: I will give your suggestion a go and report back here @UlrichSchwarz